# Swift 3 'CGContextAddArc' is unavailable: Use addArc(center:radius:startAngle:endAngle:clockwise:)

Tags: swift

I have this line of code here:

```
CGContextAddArc(context, (round(frame.size.width))/(2 * (appDelegate.webview?.scrollView.zoomScale)!), round(frame.size.height)/(2 * (appDelegate.webview?.scrollView.zoomScale)!), (round(frame.size.width) - 10)/(2 * (appDelegate.webview?.scrollView.zoomScale)!), 0.0, CGFloat(M_PI * 2.0), 1)
```

but U get this error now:

```
'CGContextAddArc' is unavailable: Use addArc(center:radius:startAngle:endAngle:clockwise:)
```

so I try to use addArc but when I start typing it, the method does not appear, How do I call addArc?

Here is my full code:

```
func drawCircle()
    {
        // Get the Graphics Context
        let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

        // Set the circle outerline-width
        context?.setLineWidth(5.0);

        // Set the circle outerline-colour
        UIColor.red.set()

        // Create Circle
        CGContextAddArc(context, (round(frame.size.width))/(2 * (appDelegate.webview?.scrollView.zoomScale)!), round(frame.size.height)/(2 * (appDelegate.webview?.scrollView.zoomScale)!), (round(frame.size.width) - 10)/(2 * (appDelegate.webview?.scrollView.zoomScale)!), 0.0, CGFloat(M_PI * 2.0), 1)

        // Draw
        context?.strokePath();
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
let center = CGPoint(x:(round(frame.size.width))/(2 * (appDelegate.webview?.scrollView.zoomScale)!), y:round(frame.size.height)/(2 * (appDelegate.webview?.scrollView.zoomScale)!))
let radius = (round(frame.size.width) - 10)/(2 * (appDelegate.webview?.scrollView.zoomScale)!)

context.addArc(center: center, radius: radius, startAngle: 0, endAngle: CGFloat(M_PI * 2.0), clockwise: true)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is objective-c syntax to draw an arc.

> CGContextAddArc(CGContextRef  _Nullable c, CGFloat x, CGFloat y, CGFloat radius, CGFloat startAngle, CGFloat endAngle, int clockwise>)

call to method : CGContextAddArc(context, x, y, 40, 0.0, M_PI * 2.0, YES);

But in swift , syntax is simpler and removed the context and replaced the x y coordinate with center.

> context?.addArc(center: CGPoint, radius: CGFloat, startAngle: CGFloat, endAngle: CGFloat, clockwise: Bool)

```
context?.addArc(center: center, radius: 40, startAngle: 0.0, endAngle: CGFloat(.pi * 2.0), clockwise: true)
```

to calculate center use following line.

```
let x = (self.bounds.origin.x + self.bounds.size.width) / 2
let y = (self.bounds.origin.y + self.bounds.size.height) / 2
let center = CGPoint(x: x, y: y)
```

add fillEllipse line.

```
context?.fillEllipse(in: rect)
```